# conditional probability on multiple random variables

Tags: conditional-probability, random-variable, expected-value

I am trying to solve the following question and I am not sure if I am thinking of the correct solution.
Given X that could take any of the following values with the corresponding probabilities:

\begin{equation}
    X=
    \begin{cases}
      0, & p =0.3 \\
      1, & p=0.4 \\
      2, & p=0.3
    \end{cases}
  \end{equation}

Let 
  \begin{equation}
    Y = 5 - X^{2} + \varepsilon
  \end{equation}
Where 
  \begin{equation}
    X ~and ~ \varepsilon
  \end{equation}
are independent and

\begin{equation}
    \varepsilon=
    \begin{cases}
      -1, & p =0.5 \\
      1, & p=0.5 
    \end{cases}
  \end{equation}

find

\begin{equation}
    g(x) = E[Y|X=x]\\
  \end{equation}
and the least squares linear predictor of Y.

Since the variables are independent can I say that

\begin{equation}
    Y=
    \begin{cases}
      4-X^{2}, & p =0.5 \\
      6-X^{2}, & p=0.5 
    \end{cases}
  \end{equation}

and would

\begin{equation}
    h(X) = \mu_Y + b\mu_X
  \end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

The third and fourth line in @nafizh's answer are incorrect.
In the third line the value of $X = x$ is given and therfore no expectation is needed.
In the fourth line the values of $\epsilon$ do not need to be squared.
\begin{eqnarray*}
g(x) = E[Y|X=x] &=& E[5 - X^2 + \epsilon|X =x]\\
       &=& E[5] - E[X^2|X=x] + E[\epsilon|X=x]) \\
       &=& 5 - x^2 + E[\epsilon] \\ 
       &=& 5 - x^2 + [-1(0.5) + 1(0.5)] \\
       &=& 5 - x^2
\end{eqnarray*}

The same result occurs from start at the last line of your working:
\begin{eqnarray*}
g(x) = E[Y|X=x] &=& 0.5 \times (4 - x^2) + 0.5 \times (6 - x^2)\\
       &=& 5 - x^2 
\end{eqnarray*}